# How to select last XX entries for each team?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
ID | team1 | team2 | Date
-----------------------------
1  |   36  |   25  | 2019-01-05
2  |   25  |   39  | 2019-01-07
3  |   36  |   39  | 2019-01-09
4  |   36  |   11  | 2019-01-10
5  |   11  |   25  | 2019-01-11
6  |   25  |   36  | 2019-01-12
```

How to get last 2 entries for team 25 and 36. Good result is:

```
ID | team1 | team2 | Date
-----------------------------
4  |   36  |   11  | 2019-01-10 > 36
5  |   11  |   25  | 2019-01-11 > 25
6  |   25  |   36  | 2019-01-12 > 25 & 36
```

25 and 36 is just for example. We can have a long list of teams, as well as a very large list of entries. If the search would be carried out on one column, for example team1 then the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    ID, team1, team2, `Date`,
    CASE WHEN @id != team1 THEN @rownum := 1 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 END AS rank,
    @id := team1
FROM matches
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id := NULL) r
WHERE team1 IN(25, 36)
OREDER BY team1, `Date` DESC
) WHERE rank <= 2
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself yet?  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Don't change the question to invalidate existing answers

Answer (score 2):

```
(SELECT * FROM teams WHERE (team1 = 25 and team2 != 36) OR (team2 = 25 and team2 != 36) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM teams WHERE team1 = 36 OR team2 = 36 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 25 IN (team1,team2) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 36 IN (team1,team2) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Is not solution, see description above.

Comment: You can remove the ALL keyword